# Field Extension problem beyond $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, galois-theory

There are lots of fields between $\mathbb C$ and Meromorphic Functions on $\mathbb C$. For example set of "All Even Meromorphic Functions on $\mathbb C$'' is a subfield between $\mathbb C$ and Meromorphic Functions on $\mathbb C$.

Question:  How to categorize such subfields ?

I have no idea whether somebody studied this or not. If somebody give me some reference it will be helpful to me.

Comment: I guess you can start with Galois theory.  For one, your example is the fixed field of the automorphism $X \mapsto -X$

Comment: Rational functions...

Answer (score 8):

The field of meromorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ is huge so I don't expect that this question has a reasonable general answer. One might ask about the fields between $\mathbb{C}$ and meromorphic functions on the Riemann sphere; these are just the rational functions $\mathbb{C}(x)$.

Since $\mathbb{C}$ is already algebraically closed, any nontrivial field between $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}(x)$ necessarily has transcendence degree $1$. Such a field $F$ necessarily lies between $\mathbb{C}(x)$ and $\mathbb{C}(f)$ for some $f \in \mathbb{C}(x)$. $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is always a finite extension of $\mathbb{C}(f)$ (exercise), so the inclusion $F \to \mathbb{C}(x)$ corresponds in the [standard way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_field_of_an_algebraic_variety) to a branched cover of compact [Riemann surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface) (equivalently, smooth projective [algebraic curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve) over $\mathbb{C}$)
$$\mathbb{CP}^1 \to S$$

where $S$ is the Riemann surface with function field $F$. By [Riemann-Hurwitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hurwitz_formula), this can only occur if $S \cong \mathbb{CP}^1$, hence we can choose $f$ so that $F \cong \mathbb{C}(f)$. Thus all nontrivial subfields of $\mathbb{C}(x)$ are of the form $\mathbb{C}(f)$ for some rational function $f$.

On the other hand, $\text{Aut}_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathbb{C}(x))$ is an interesting group; explicitly it consists of all [Möbius transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) $z \mapsto \frac{az + b}{cz + d}, ad - bc \neq 0$ and abstractly it is $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{C}) \cong \text{PSL}_2(\mathbb{C})$, the [projective special linear group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group) in $2$ dimensions over $\mathbb{C}$. The fixed field of any subgroup of $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ is therefore a subfield of $\mathbb{C}(x)$. Special among these are the finite subgroups. By an averaging argument each of these are contained in the [projective special unitary group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_unitary_group#Projective_special_unitary_group) $\text{PSU}_2$, which is well-known to be isomorphic to $\text{SO}(3)$, and the finite subgroups of this are (more or less) the groups of symmetries of the [Platonic solids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid). The study of the finite subgroups of any of the above related groups is quite fascinating; one entry into further study is the various answers in [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16026/the-finite-subgroups-of-sl2-c).